# Keycloak Authentication with mobile number and otp

Tags: keycloak

I'm implementing the Keycloak authentication with vertx. I would like to customize login flow, instead of `username/password` form I want to login via mobile number and `OTP`.
Any one can help me if they have created any custom required action provider in keycloak.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, I am working as the same feature just like you and currently stuck with it. Did you do the implement for this feature?

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/10/23/use-mobile-numbers-for-user-authentication-in-keycloak/

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be doable in Keycloak now with `Authenticator SPI`. Please have a look on this [code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/resetcred/ResetCredentialChooseUser.java) you will get to know you can revamp full login flow without much issue .
Same can be rewrite for login from mobile number.

Please have a look this API [keycloak-sms-authenticator](https://github.com/gwallet/keycloak-sms-authenticator),it will give much flexibility to do SMS based Authentication without writing much line of code.

Here is another good official documentation [Custom User Attributes](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/server_development/topics/custom-attributes.html) available  how to use mobile number  .

Comment: Anyone successfully able to implement this extension?

Comment: @zeze Have a look on this https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/ad3aa0e36d33d067dba2

Comment: We want to implement the same flow; is there anyone implemented the same flow. We trying to implement Twilio for the same flow in Keycloak 11.0.2

Comment: @SubodhJoshi https://github.com/gwallet/keycloak-sms-authenticator shows username/password before presenting a screen for accepting mobile numbers. So this doesn't work as expected, the expectation was to use the mobile number and send OTP for authentication

Comment: @MohankumarD we are looking for something similar but with a different SMS provider. Let us know if you find anything

Comment: @Rpj have a look this https://github.com/UKGovernmentBEIS/keycloak-sms-authenticator-sns

Comment: @SubodhJoshi does this plugin still expect the user to login using username/password and then ask you for the OTP? We saw similar behaviour, kindly confirm

Comment: @Rpj Sorry I didnt tested the plugin